# Cookie doesn't show as a client cookie. Javascript

Tags: node.js, express, backend

I'm using a company's API.

When I log in, it sends me a cookie.

With the command below, I get this cookie.

```
const loginSysaidCookie = response.headers.get('set-cookie')
```

Then I give the console:

```
console.log("loginSysaidCookie with convert", loginSysaidCookie)
```

Console ->

> loginSysaidCookie com convertida [
> 'JSESSIONID=796330316C3EC071ED53338C108C4A99.inst15eu-autoscaleapp-002161; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax',
> 'SERVERID=inst15eu-autoscale-app0|Y3+Qq|Y3+Qq; path=/'
> ]

To send this cookie from the client to my API I am using. the command below:

```
res.cookie('JSESSIONID', loginSysaidCookie[0])
res.cookie('SERVERID', loginSysaidCookie[1])
```

But I still have this ->

> 'Cookie': 'JSESSIONID=JSESSIONID%3DD239C020B874EFEB3DD6DED7055DDC3B.inst15eu-autoscaleapp-002161%3B%20Path%3D%2F%3B%20Secure%3B%20HttpOnly%3B%20SameSite%3DLax; SERVERID=SERVERID%3Dinst15eu-autoscale-app0%7CY3%2BTF%7CY3%2BTF%3B%20path%3D%2F'

The client cookie looks like this ->>

> 'Cookie': 'JSESSIONID=85ABA2700058749DB748C3C7398B7667.inst15eu-autoscaleapp-002161; SERVERID=inst15eu-autoscale-app0|Y3+Bg|Y3+Bg'
>
> -----------------------------
>
> **From Post Man cookies**
>
> JSESSIONID=85ABA2700058749DB748C3C7398B7667.inst15eu-autoscaleapp-002161; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly;
>
> SERVERID=inst15eu-autoscale-app0|Y3+Bg|Y3+Bg; Path=/;

My cookie looks like this -->

> 'Cookie': 'JSESSIONID=JSESSIONID%3DD239C020B874EFEB3DD6DED7055DDC3B.inst15eu-autoscaleapp-002161%3B%20Path%3D%2F%3B%20Secure%3B%20HttpOnly%3B%20SameSite%3DLax; SERVERID=SERVERID%3Dinst15eu-autoscale-app0%7CY3%2BTF%7CY3%2BTF%3B%20path%3D%2F'
>
> ------------------------------
>
> **From Post Man cookies**
>
> JSESSIONID=JSESSIONID%3DD239C020B874EFEB3DD6DED7055DDC3B.inst15eu-autoscaleapp-002161%3B%20Path%3D%2F%3B%20Secure%3B%20HttpOnly%3B%20SameSite%3DLax; Path=/;
>
> SERVERID=SERVERID%3Dinst15eu-autoscale-app0%7CY3%2BTF%7CY3%2BTF%3B%20path%3D%2F; Path=/;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each entry in `loginSysaidCookie` is a "set cookie instruction" of the form

```js
JSESSIONID=<value>; Path=<path>; Secure; HttpOnly; SameSite=<strict/lax/none>
```

To set this cookie in your response `res`, you must

```js
res.cookie("JSESSIONID", "<value>", {
  path: "<path>",
  secure: true,
  httpOnly: true,
  sameSite: "<strict/lax/none>"
});
```

But you give the entire "set cookie instruction" as the value, that's why you see `JSESSIONID=JSESSIONID...`.

If you don't want to parse the "set cookie instruction" into its constituent parts, you can simply

```js
res.setHeader('Set-Cookie', loginSysaidCookie[0]);
res.setHeader('Set-Cookie', loginSysaidCookie[1]);
```

this works because the cookie you receive from your company's API contains neither a `Domain` attribute nor a `Path` other than `/`. If it did, you would probably have to change that attribute before sending the cookie from your server.